# Chef Files Resource

Tags: ruby, devops, chef-infra

Currently working on pushing a configuration file with a blank password variable to my linux instance(s). I am able to transfer the directory holding this config file using the remote_directory resource in Chef. Is there any way to either:

1. Place the password in the configuration file, which is located in the files directory within the cookbook and then encrypt that file so if anybody gets access to it, it won't show in plan text?
2. Using a ruby block to adjust the file content?

Comment: Have a look at [data bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags/), the native way to store and transfer sensitive data to the nodes.

Comment: How could you transfer the sensitive data from the data bag to a configuration file?

Comment: Check the link in my comment. It shows how to create data bags, and how to load them in a recipe.

Comment: The link doesn't go over how to place that data within a configuration file. The file is being transferred to the instance using the remote_directory resource with a blank password within. I am looking to see if it's possible to use either a data bag or another method to place the sensitive data in the configuration file after it has been transferred.

Comment: It **does** show how to [use it](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags/#use-data-bags). Basically, you read the data bag into a variable, like `admins = data_bag('admins')`.  Since the `admins` variable now has contents of the data bag (`admins`), you can use it how ever you need (in files).